# How to trigger PHP function by a timer

Tags: php, sql

I'm making program what inserts data into a database. I have this button:

```
<form method='post'>
```

When it is pressed it inserts some data in the database.

I want to make a function that, when a button is pressed, waits for *x* time and then inserts data in the database.

I want to give a player the illusion that some building is under construction, and it will level up after some time.

`sleep()` doesn't work because it pauses the whole site, and doesn't allow to progress in other constructions.

Comment: instead of delaying the insert, insert immediately with an additional column of `available_at` containing the timestamp when the item is available.

Comment: You can use ajax for creating illusion but why do you want to delay insertion in database

Comment: The problem is that one building have 20lvls so the construction time ghrows when upgrading the building.

Comment: i want to delay it because in other way the database shows the level , it inserts data in, and fech it in other place ? sorry my bad eng.

Comment: example my warehouse is int 0 in db,

Comment: and it shows on site that warehouse is lvl 0 , whn u insert +1 it lvl ghrows by 1 , and on site it shows 1. I want to delay it because otherwice on button click it shows str8 lvl1

Comment: i have been learning coding for 2 months , and only php .

Comment: when i tried to understand ajax , i got confused :DD

Comment: not yet i refresh it by header('Refresh: 1');function is done (:

Comment: Lvl up:  <form method='post'><input name='barraks' id='lvlUpB' type='submit' value='LvlUp' /></form>   <br>";

Comment: I made the javascript timer anyway (as an answer). It could be useful for you.

Comment: thanks for the answerrs !

Answer (score 0):

Copy-paste next code in a PHP file and open it in your browser, it waits 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds) then submits the form (this javascript timer may help you) :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var tmr;
function wait_before_submit ( seconds )
{ tmr = setTimeout( wait_seconds,seconds ); // TIMER START.
}
function wait_seconds ()
{ clearTimeout( tmr );           // TIMER END.
  document.getElementById("frm").submit(); // SUBMIT FORM.
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="frm" method="post" action="some_script.php">
      <input type="text" name="txt"/>
    </form>
    <!-- ▼ NOTICE THIS BUTTON IS OUTSIDE THE FORM ▼ -->
    <button onclick="wait_before_submit(5000)">Submit</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: problem is that i need the timer inside the php code, because it need to - resourses if u hit the button.

Comment: @Chillinprogrammer, if "sleep" stops the whole site, then you will need javascript, because javascript timers allow other parts to continue working.

Comment: @Chillinprogrammer, also you will need ajax.

Comment: Jeah i read , and my friend told me too , but i think that i am just too retard to understand it :D I read about it here too but still dont get how it goes :(

Comment: And im surprised about how limited php is  :(((

Comment: @Chillinprogrammer, it is not limited, but it is server side, it's a natural limitation. Now, in order to use ajax, it will be easier to split your code in fragments, each in its own PHP file, so we can call them with ajax and do something in the mean time (like waiting 5 seconds while a building constructs).

Comment: By the way, it maybe a stupid question but do i have allways to split my code in fragments when using ajax. Im asking because in school we havent look how it works but my friend told me how to auto update with setinterval() . He took my output off a chat to another php file and its worked but im wondering do i have to do same with all my autoupdating parts (4parts per tab/ in some 10 tabs)sound kinda not logical? Can it be done like 1 php file with ajax updates all the other parts?

Comment: @Chillinprogrammer, no, you don't have to split your code always.